# Get full path from view in MVC .net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

Im trying to upload a picture in a MVC app build on .net
I made a button :

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Imagen, 
                new { htmlAttributes = new{ @class = "input", @type="file" } })
```

But it only gets the name of the picture. I read thats because of security reasons, so what is the simplest way of get the full path of my picture?
I can use anything (.net framework)

Answer (score 0):

The uploaded file doesn't have a path until you save it somewhere. Your Action should receive an HttpPostedFileBase object from the post which you can use to do this.

A simple example:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase upload)
{
  var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\uploads\", upload.FileName);
  upload.SaveAs(filePath);
}
```